# popping out a number from a stack list (linked list)?

Tags: c++, class, linked-list

```
class stack_class
{
private:

    struct stack_struct *head;

public:
    stack_class();
    ~stack_class();
    void pushNumber(int number);
    void popNumber();
    void findNumber();
    void clearStack();
    void sizeFinder();
    void printStack();

};

void stack_class::popNumber()
{
    stack_struct *pointerPop=NULL,*pointerPop2=NULL;
    int popCounter=0,i=0;
    pointerPop2=tailPointer;
    if(head==NULL)
    {
        cout<<"\nNo Member to Delete.\n";
    }
    else
    {
        while(pointerPop2)
        {
            popCounter++;
            //cout<<pointerFunc3->number<<endl;
            pointerPop2=pointerPop2->next_number;
        }
        pointerPop=tailPointer;
        while(i<(popCounter-2))
        {
            pointerPop=pointerPop->next_number;
            i++;
        }
        pointerPop->next_number=NULL;
        delete head;
        head=pointerPop;
    }

}

void stack_class::printStack()
{
    pointerFunc3=tailPointer;
    if(tailPointer==NULL)
    {
        cout<<"\nNo Members in List.\n";
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<"\n\nList Is:\n";
        while(pointerFunc3)
        {
            cout<<pointerFunc3->number<<endl;
            pointerFunc3=pointerFunc3->next_number;
        }
    }

}
```

constructor to class

```
stack_class::stack_class()
{
    head=NULL;
}
```

This is my code, the problem with it is, when I POP the very last number and try to print the list, it enters an infinite loop and prints garbage. when I press the delete option after everything in the list has been deleted, the program freezes. Any suggestions why this is acting like this??And how do I fix it?

Comment: Does your class implement a constructor?

Comment: @AlexB yes, there is a constructor and a destructor. I will add it if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The condition of your first while loop will never be false. Depending on how you've implemented your next_number (if it's a circular linked list), I believe you should change it to:

```
while(pointerPop2 != head)
```

if you want it to loop through all nodes.

Comment: actually the loop goes through the entire thing, the problem I am having is when the very last node is deleted, the program prints garbage.